# AWS - PHP form to send email - doesn't send email to same domain

Tags: php, forms, email, amazon-web-services, smtp

I have my website hosted on Amazon Web Services EC2, I have created a php form to send email, I have successfully validated my email address using Amazon SES and this is the problem:

- email to xxx@xxx works fine
- email to xxx@mydomain are not received

I read on this page ([Can't receive mail from a Web Form](https://support.google.com/a/answer/55299?hl=en)) that there could be a problem with same domain configuration.

Does anyone know how can I fix this? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem using the following code:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23002849/4063626

and including:

class.phpmailer.php: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php
class.smtp.php: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.smtp.php

Thanks